# Lightdm can't start guest session

Tags: login, lightdm, login-screen, guest-session, unity-greeter

Something weird happened to my lightdm after removing the Gnome shell. The input fields has become white instead of the standard transparent, and, most importantly, I am unable to start guest sessions. When clicking the button for logging in as guest the following messages appear on screen:

```
Logging in...
Failed to start session
```

Why has this happened? And how can I fix it?

Comment: You apparently removed too much. Try `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson This didn't change anything, even after reboot. Just installed a lot of unnecessary packages

Comment: Is it from unity-greeter you can't start a guest session? If so, can you start it from the system menu within a regular session?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson If I try to do it from the system menu, the unity lock screen is started and no guest-session starts

Comment: It may be something with the lightdm configuration then. Did you make changes in e.g. `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d`, `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` or `/etc/guest-session`?

Comment: My `/etc/guest-session` is empty, so that may be the problem if it's not supposed to be

Comment: No, that's not a problem; it's empty by default. So is `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for me was to remove the file `/etc/.pwd.lock`. I don't know why, but I read on a bug report page that deleting `.lock` files in the `/etc` directory often fixes guest login problems.

It didn't change the white input fields, but that is probably totally unrelated, it only changed at the same time.

Comment: Ok, thanks for sharing. (I had never heard of that as a potential guest session problem.)